# I define nested schema , when i fill the inputs it returns nothing and not save in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, nested, schema

I define nested schema but when I send input data returns nothing,
how can I solve this issue ?
this is my result:

```
{
    "message": "handeling post request to /user-api",
    "CreatedUserInfo": {
       "_id": "5cbb7fbaad28fe209099a57c"
    }
}
```

this is my code :

```
const userEduSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        eduLevel : String ,
        eduField : String,
        eduInst :String,
        eduCity :String,
        eduDate :Date,
        proposalTitle :String
}
)

const allEduSchema = new  mongoose.Schema(
    {
        bsc: userEduSchema, 
       master: userEduSchema,
        phd:  userEduSchema , 
}
) 

module.exports =  mongoose.model('Users', allEduSchema )
```

and it is my `user.js` for save inpute data in MongoDB I don't know this is true or not:

````
const userModels = require('../../models/userModels')

router.post('/', (req , res, next) => {
const user = new userModels({
 _id : new mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
eduLevel :req.body.eduLevel,
eduField :req.body.eduField,
eduInst :req.body.eduInst,
eduCity :req.body.eduCity,
eduDate :req.body.eduDates,
proposalTitle :req.body.proposalTitle,
})
user.save().then(result =>{
    console.log(result)
}).catch (err => {
    console.log(err)
})
    res.status(201).json ({
        message:'handeling post request to /user-api',
        CreatedUserInfo : user
})
})```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in defining the way of get the inputs,I must define the nested object and inside of that put the request bodies as well as I define the nested schema.

```
bsc:{
bscEduLevel :req.body.bscEduLevel,
    bscEduField :req.body.bscEduField,
    bscEduInst :req.body.bscEduInst,
    bscEduCity :req.body.bscEduCity,
    bscEduDate :req.body.bscEduDate,
    bscProposalTitle :req.body.bscProposalTitle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined `userSchema`? If not, you are trying to export a schema which does not exist. Again, in case you have not defined `userSchema` and you want to export `allEduSchema`, replace the last line of your model file with this:

```
const EduSchema = mongoose.model("EduSchema", allEduSchema);
module.exports = EduSchema;
```

Comment: thank u , yes I define it in my code and i edit it in my question , still it doesn't return anything :(

Comment: What are you trying to do? Did you try Users.find()?

Comment: I want to save my inputs in the database, I post them but when i fetch the data it doesn't return anything and in database just save the _id!!!

Comment: I see that you create a `userEduSchema` model and not a `allEduSchema` one. You have to use this instead `module.exports =  mongoose.model('Users', userEduSchema )`. Also you don't need to create the _id

Comment: Unfortunately no , when I define simple schema it works but when define like nested it doesn't. I think the problem is in my schema but don't know where!?

Comment: Where do you need the `allEduSchema` schema?

Comment: I want to use the property of _ userEduSchema_ for bsc as well as for master and phd because the properties are the same I use nested schema .

Comment: After creating each user (e.g. `const userBsc = new userModels(..)` ,  `const userMaster= new userModels(..)` and so on, you can create a new model of `allEduSchema` (e.g. allEduUser) like this `const userAllEdu = new allEduUser({bsc: userBsc, master: userMaster, phd:  userPhd})`. Note that you should export the `allEduSchema` schema as well.

Answer (score 0):

Before you create a new user ,you need to require your "User" moongose Schema. Just like dimitris tseggenes said.

I use async function  and try/catch to handle this problem.Maybe you could....

```
router.post("/", async (request, response) => {
try {
   const user  = new Users({new user's data here..... });
   const  result = await user.save();
    response.send(result);
} catch (error) {
    response.status(400).send(error);
}
```

});

try catch could avoid some unexpected error and handle it.